# Help with Training and Testing Classifier errors

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to understand if classifier X has smaller training error than classifier Y, then classifier X will have smaller generalization (test) error than classifier Y. ( Answer  is False)

My understanding is below:

They can be totally different(training error and test error) if
train distribution is not equal to test distribution.
Even under the same distribution, they can be very different.
Because h is picked to minimize training error, not test error.
Let me know if my understanding is correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h$ is picked to minimized a loss function of which part of it usually would have included the training error. Some loss function would have included some regularization to improve the generalization performance.

A small training error doesn't mean good generalization for sure. The classifier could have been overfitted to the training data and have very poor generalization performance.  For example, a classifier that would have just memorize the training data with no learning would predict randomly on unseen data. This would be a very bad classifier and we can observe that during test or validation.